# Akka.Net, Cluster Client: How to send message directly to an actor in the cluster?

Tags: akka.net

My Usecase: I want to use Akka.Streams Remote via the cluster and the (cluster) client

In the docu https://getakka.net/articles/clustering/cluster-client.html it is mentioned that "It is possible to pass the original sender inside the reply messages if the client is supposed to communicate directly to the actor in the cluster." but that does not seem to work for me. I use the cluster client to get a message containing an actor reference (IActorRef) from the cluster (not the actor, which replied but another one ).

When I am trying to send a message to that very actor afterwards I get a dead letter and even the client sometimes looses contact to the cluster. Is the docu wrong here or is my understanding wrong here ?

Remark: communicating via the ClusterClient.Send() functionality works fine

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the message was just not serializable, that was the reason.